# How to read and write Enum into parcel on Android?

Tags: android, enums, parcelable, parcel

Here is my model class:

```
public enum Action {
    RETRY, SETTINGS
}

private int imageId;
private String description;
private String actionName;
private Action action;

public NetworkError(int imageId, String description, String actionName, Action action ) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.description = description;
    this.actionName = actionName;
    this.action = action;
}

public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}

public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getActionName() {
    return actionName;
}

public void setActionName(String actionName) {
    this.actionName = actionName;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.imageId);
    dest.writeString(this.description);
    dest.writeString(this.actionName);
}

protected NetworkError(Parcel in) {
    this.imageId = in.readInt();
    this.description = in.readString();
    this.actionName = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<NetworkError> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<NetworkError>() {
    @Override
    public NetworkError createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new NetworkError(source);
    }

    @Override
    public NetworkError[] newArray(int size) {
        return new NetworkError[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: Enums are `Serializable`.

Comment: http://www.parcelabler.com/

Comment: have you tried `dest.writeValue()`

Answer (score 87):

I had similar problem and my solution was:

```
parcel.writeString(this.questionType.name());
```

and for reading :

```
this.questionType = QuestionType.valueOf(parcel.readString());
```

`QuestionType` is enum and remember that ordering of elements matters.

Comment: Perfect Answer :)

Answer (score 49):

The most efficient - memory efficient - bundle is created by using the ENUM ordinal value.

Writing to Parcel `dest.writeInt(enum_variable.ordinal());`

Reading from parcel `enum_variable = EnumName.values()[in.readInt()];`

This should be fine unless you don't heed the documentation's admonitions:

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

In other words, you shouldn't pass Parcels between code versions because it may not work.

Comment: I can already see the people aggressively upvoting the `string` answer over this `ordinal` answer, because normally you're always discouraged from using `.ordinal()`, but given the caveat you mentioned, this is one of the acceptable use cases

Comment: Yes, you have to be aware of the restrictions of Parcels. Personally try to use Protobufs as much as possible because they work in golang, kotlin, java, dart, etc. This means I don't have to deal with several different ways of packing and unpacking the same data. (Still no "Correct Answer" maked for this...)

Answer (score 35):

Any `enum` is serializable.

You can do this in `writeToParcel()`: `dest.writeSerializable(action)`

And in the constructor: `action = (Action) in.readSerializable()`

Comment: This is the easiest solution to implement but considering `serializable` interface is much slower than `parcelable`, I wonder if this has any effect on performance compared to the answers below where you cast the `enum` to a more primitive type.

Answer (score 5):

Enum decleration:

```
public enum Action {

    NEXT(1),
    OK(2);

    private int action;

    Action(int action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

}
```

**Reading from Parcel:**

```
protected ActionParcel(Parcel in) {
    int actionTmp = in.readInt();
    action = Tutorials.Action.values()[actionTmp];
}
```

**Writing to parcel:**

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    int actionTmp = action == null ? -1 : action.ordinal();
    dest.writeInt(actionTmp);
}
```

Comment: Don't know why other methods were throwing exceptions. This method worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Now, you can write something like this using Kotlin Parcelize:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class NetworkError(
    var imageId: Int,
    var description: String,
    var actionName: String,
    private val action: Action
): Parcelable {

    @Parcelize
    enum class Action: Parcelable {
        RETRY, SETTINGS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sample Kotlin-Code (null-safe):

```
writeInt(action?.ordinal ?: -1)

action = readInt().let { if (it >= 0) enumValues<MyEnum>()[it] else null }
```

Which can be encapsulated in a write/readEnum Methods as extensions to Parcel:

```
fun <T : Enum<T>> Parcel.writeEnum(value: T?) = 
    writeInt(value?.ordinal ?: -1)

inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> Parcel.readEnum(): T? = 
    readInt().let { if (it >= 0) enumValues<T>()[it] else null }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to write Actions in integer and read them properly as integer and convert them into Action. What I mean:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.imageId);
    dest.writeString(this.description);
    dest.writeString(this.actionName);

    int actionAsInt = action == Action.RETRY ? 1 : 0;
    dest.writeInt(actionAsInt);
}

protected NetworkError(Parcel in) {
    this.imageId = in.readInt();
    this.description = in.readString();
    this.actionName = in.readString();

    int actionAsInt = in.readInt();
    this.action = actionAsInt == 1 ? Action.RETRY : Action.SETTINGS;
}
```

Try it. Success ...

Answer (score 1):

Read parcel

```
action = Nav.valueOf(in.readString());
```

Write parcel

```
out.writeString(action.name());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

```
@Parcelize enum class State {
    ON, OFF
}

@Parcelize
class PowerSwitch(var state: State) : Parcelable
```

Let me know it work for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

*Using the fact that enums are serializeable*

My enum:

```
public enum HouseEnum {
    GRYFFINDOR, HUFFLEPUFF, RAVENCLAW, SLYTHERIN
}
```

When placing in bundle:

```
args.putSerializable(HOUSE, houseEnum);
```

When retrieving from bundle:

```
houseEnum = (HouseEnum) getArguments().getSerializable(HOUSE);
```