# write parcelable on enum is crashing the app

Tags: java, android, enums, parcelable

This line is `dest.writeParcelable(department, flags);` causing the app to crash as I parcel the object via the intent.

When I comment the line, the app goes through but of course I don't have the department value.

```
public class User implements Parcelable {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public Department department;

    // other implementations of Parcelable 

protected UserVO(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    email = in.readString();
    department = in.readParcelable(Department.class.getClassLoader());
}


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(email);
        dest.writeParcelable(department, flags); // crashes
    }
}
```

**Department Enum**

```
public enum Department implements Parcelable {

    SALES("Sales", 1),
    HR("Human Resources", 2),
    SHIPPING("Shipping", 3),

    public final String name;
    public final int ordinal;

    Department(String name, int ordinal) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
    }

    Department(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        ordinal = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Department> CREATOR = new Creator<Department>() {
        @Override
        public Department createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return Department.valueOf(in.readString()); // crash
            //return new DeptEnum(in); // android studio generated code but has error: enum types may not be instantiated
        }

        @Override
        public Department[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Department[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeInt(ordinal);
    }
}
```

**Error**

> No enum constant Department.Sales

I took the help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174961/how-to-read-and-write-enum-into-parcel-on-android) for the line `return Department.valueOf(in.readString());`

---

**Observation**

I guess it has to do something with having both name and ordinal values, my enum type is not simple as in the linked answer, somehow I need to create an enum from parcel.

```
public Department createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    Log.d("abc", "createFromParcel: " + in.readString()); // returns null
    Log.d("abc", "createFromParcel: " + in.readInt()); // returns 127 or 128
    return SHIPPING; // hard coded value works but of course not a solution
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, enums are serializable. Try removing all the `Parcelable` stuff and use `writeSerializable()`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please help with the code on where and how to write, I'm new to this, you mean `dest.writeSerializable(department);`?

Comment: please also look into `in.readParcelable(Department.class.getClassLoader());`, any changes here?

Comment: I tried `writeSerializable`, but has exception `android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires subclassing from Parcelable on Department`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parcel the ordinal. Doing valueOf alone on the name would be fine

However, the parameter of valueOf must match **exactly** the enum defined name.

For example, this would work for sales and shipping, but not HR

```
Department.valueOf(in.readString().toUpperCase());
```

---

The solution you need is to loop over `Department.values()` and compare each name field of the values with the in.readString() result

[How can I lookup a Java enum from its String value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080904/how-can-i-lookup-a-java-enum-from-its-string-value)

Or you could use the ordinal instead like so, although you're duplicating ordinal information and you'd have to guarantee that the enums have sequential numbers

```
 return Department.values()[in.readInt() - 1]
```

Comment: or shall I go the other way around, writing and reading ordinal? to make it simple and easy

Comment: There's no guarantee it would not also be null, but `return Department.values()[in.readInt() - 1]` could work

Comment: not null meaning someone doesn't specify an ordinal?

Comment: You're using an enum, so all the values need to be defined. And ints cannot be null anyway

Comment: I'm using ordinal approach since you said it won't work with HR, I just want to clarify what do you mean by `There's no guarantee it would not also be null`

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't, then. But if it returns 0, my logic there would give out of bounds exception

Comment: yes and i make sure to start my ordinal from 0, i started 1 here

Comment: also it felt to me that `in` parcel is some kind of a streaming or seek operation, once I read a value, I can't read it back again.